# ¿A qué hace referencia "lo" en "lo flipo"?

Tags: verbos, pronombres, españa, clíticos

Según el DLE, y eliminando las acepciones referentes a drogas:

> **[flipar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I5m76DG)**
>
> Del ingl. *to flip [out]* 'perder el control bajo los efectos de las
>   drogas', 'volverse loco'.
>
> 2. intr. coloq. Esp. Estar o quedar maravillado o admirado. *La gente flipaba CON la música.* U. t. c. prnl.
> 3. intr. coloq. Esp. Estar o quedar asombrado o extrañado. *Flipamos al saber que fue monja.*
> 4. intr. coloq. Esp. Agradar o gustar mucho a alguien. *Me flipan las motos.*

Como se ve, todas las acepciones marcan el verbo como intransitivo. Además, la acepción 2 admite su uso como pronominal, lo que permite construcciones como:

> La gente se flipaba con la música.

Sin embargo, a menudo se ven construcciones como (parafraseando los ejemplos):

> La gente lo flipaba con la música.
>   Lo flipamos al saber que fue monja.

Si el verbo es intransitivo, ¿cuál es la función de "lo" en esas frases? ¿Qué es lo que se flipa? ¿Es simplemente un uso incorrecto del verbo *flipar*?

Un ejemplo extraído del CREA:

> *Y con un culo que lo flipas, aunque lo propio sería decir que te cagas.*
>
> Begoña Ameztoy, "Escuela de mujeres", 2001 (España).

Answer (score 4):

Creo que la lista de acepciones del a RAE no es del todo completa. Creo que muchas veces se usa "flipar" con el sentido de [alucinar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=28fwlxV), que sí es transitivo

> 2. tr. Sorprender, asombrar, deslumbrar. U. t. c. intr. y c. prnl.
> 3. tr. coloq. Arg. Fantasear, imaginar vivamente algo. Aluciné que viajaba por el espacio.
> 4. prnl. Confundirse, desvariar.

Adaptado a los ejemplos

> La gente **alucinó** con la música. <sub>Se sorprendió o asombró con la música</sub>
>
> **Alucinamos** al saber que fue monja.<sub>Nos sorprendimos y asombramos con la noticia</sub>
>
> Me **alucinan** las motos. <sub>me gustan las motos hasta el punto del asombro, la fantasía o el desvarío</sub>
>
> Y con un culo que lo **alucinas**[...] <sub>asombro, desvarío, un culo que deslumbra</sub>

Por eso entiendo que en muchos casos se usa `flipar` con un significado parecido a este `alucinar` (transitivo en incluso pronominal), y por eso se incluye el `lo`. Es como un "**lo** entiendo" ("absorbo esta información y *comprendo*"), pero que quiere decir "absorbo esta información y me hace *flipar* o *alucinar*".

Comment: Creo que es más bien al revés, que se usa alucinar como intransitivo, cmo en los ejemplos que pones.

Answer (score 0):

¡Buenas! A mi parecer es una forma de expresarse. A lo que está haciendo referencia con "lo flipas", es como decir:

> *"Lo sientes"*

es un equivalente a:

> *"Lo vas a sentir"*

Quizás:

> *"Te vas a sorprender"*

Como decía en comentarios. Tengo entendido que no es congruente el "lo", para el significado implícito de la expresión, pero a mi entender, parecería un mal uso del gramatical del "lo", ya que la expresión en sí es coloquial. Como podemos suponer, dichas expresiones no suelen respetar las reglas gramaticales.

Y como bien dices, estas frases suelen provenir de frases o bien de ideas bien planteadas, que con el tiempo se deforman.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en el significado, pero ¿qué es "lo" estrictamente hablando?

Comment: Tenía entendido en que lo estás pasando, pero entiendo que no es congruente el lo, para el significado tácito de la expresión. A mi entender, parecería un mal uso del "lo", ya que la expresión en sí es coloquial, no creo que respete las reglas gramaticales.

Comment: Interesante, sí es cierto que las expresiones no suelen ser especialmente correctas gramaticalmente. Sin embargo, suelen venir de algo que sí lo era y con el tiempo se _pervierten_. Sería interesante pues que añadieras esto en la respuesta.

Comment: Ok, ahi lo agrego.

Comment: Gracias, está mejor así.